# Doctrine always returns NULL in a ManyToOne relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony 4 and Doctrine.

I've got an entity `OS` with a few ManyToOne relations, and they all work fine, except for one (`$motif_non_faisabilite`) which always appears `NULL`, and that even if I make the relation non-nullable. The foreign key is set as it should in the database and `doctrine:schema:validate` says everything is ok. I even deleted and regenerated the problematic entity as well as the relation using `make:entity`, but nothing works.

I found the problem while trying to update an instance of `OS` in a controller, everything else gets updated as it should but `$motif_non_faisabilite` stays `NULL` whatever I try. While looking for a solution, I found that `$motif_non_faisabilite` doesn't even exist in `$em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($os)`.

When I populate the relation directly inside the db, then get the OS in a controller and dump it, `$motif_non_faisabilite` still shows up as `NULL`.

```
class OS
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TypeOS")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $type_os;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\StatusOS")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $status_os;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     */
    private $expert;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MotifNonFaisabilite")
     */
    private $motif_non_faisabilite;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTypeOs(): TypeOS
    {
        return $this->type_os;
    }

    public function setTypeOs(TypeOS $type_os): self
    {
        $this->type_os = $type_os;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatusOs(): StatusOS
    {
        return $this->status_os;
    }

    public function setStatusOs(StatusOS $status_os): self
    {
        $this->status_os = $status_os;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getExpert(): ?User
    {
        return $this->expert;
    }

    public function setExpert(?User $expert): self
    {
        $this->expert = $expert;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getMotifNonFaisabilite(): ?MotifNonFaisabilite
    {
        return $this->motif_non_faisabilite;
    }

    public function setMotifNonFaisabilite(?MotifNonFaisabilite $motif_non_faisabilite): self
    {
        $this->motif_non_faisabilite = $motif_non_faisabilite;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
class MotifNonFaisabilite
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $is_active = true;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getValue(): ?string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(string $value): self
    {
        $this->value = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsActive(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->is_active;
    }

    public function setIsActive(bool $is_active): self
    {
        $this->is_active = $is_active;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is the simplified controller that I use to try and debug this:

```
/**
     * @Route("/api/non-faisabilite/{os_id}", name="post_non_faisabilite", methods={"POST"}, requirements={"os_id"="\d+"})
     * @param int $os_id
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function postNonFaisabilite(int $os_id, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $os = $em->getRepository(OS::class)->find($os_id);
        var_dump($os); //see first dump below

        $motif_non_faisabilite = $em->getRepository(MotifNonFaisabilite::class)->find($data->id);
        $os->setMotifNonFaisabilite($motif_non_faisabilite);
        $em->persist($os);
        var_dump($os); //see second dump below
        $em->flush();
    }
```

First dump *(I get that same result even when motif_non_faisabilite_id is not `NULL` and even non-nullable in the db)*:

```
object(App\Entity\OS)[655]
  private 'id' => int 69123
  private 'type_os' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\TypeOS)[676]
      /**...*/
  private 'status_os' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\StatusOS)[684]
      /**...*/
  private 'expert' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User)[728]
      /**...*/
  private 'motif_non_faisabilite' => null
```

Second dump *(with this, I'm sure that when `$os` gets persisted, `$motif_non_faisabilite` isn't `NULL`)*:

```
object(App\Entity\OS)[655]
  private 'id' => int 69123
  private 'type_os' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\TypeOS)[676]
      /**...*/
  private 'status_os' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\StatusOS)[684]
      /**...*/
  private 'expert' => 
    object(Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User)[728]
      /**...*/
  private 'motif_non_faisabilite' => 
    object(App\Entity\MotifNonFaisabilite)[802]
      private 'id' => int 2
      /**...*/
```

This is driving me crazy, am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Could be that lazy loading is masking things.  Go ahead and load the second entity before dumping. $os = ...; $os->getMotifNonFaisabilite(); dump($os);  And use the Symfony dump function instead of var_dump.  It does a better job of showing entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the trick was actually to restart the server... neither `cache:clear` nor `doctrine:cache:clear-*` did anything but restarting it entirely worked.